# FileNotFoundException java cannot basic find file while it's there

Tags: java, file, filereader, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to read a basic txt file that contains prices in euros. My program is supposed to loop through these prices and then create a new file with the other prices. Now, the problem is that java says it cannot find the first file.

It is in the exact same package like this:

[image]

Java already fails at the following code:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("prices_usd.txt");
```

Whole code :

```
import java.io.*;

public class DollarToEur {
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("prices_usd.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("prices_eur");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

    String regel = br.readLine();
    while(regel != null) {
        String[] values = regel.split(" : ");
        String beschrijving = values[0];
        String prijsString = values[1];
        double prijs = Double.parseDouble(prijsString);
        double newPrijs = prijs * 0.913;

        pw.println(beschrijving + " : " + newPrijs);
        regel = br.readLine();
    }
    pw.close();
    br.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: The path is relative to the root of your package structure, not relative to the Class you are in. Try "week5/practicum13/prices_usd.txt" or move your file to a resources folder that is included in the project or to the root of your classes.

Comment: Probably the class file is being executed in a different folder. Try to find the DollarToEur.class and move the txt file there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to do:

1. Put the file directly under the project folder in Eclipse. *When your execute your code in Eclipse, the project folder is considered to be the working directory. So you need to put the file there so that Java can find it.*
2. Rename the file correctly with the `.txt` extn. *From your screen print it looks like the file does not have an extension or may be it's just not visible.*

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your file looks to be named "prices_usd" and your code is looking for "prices_usd.txt"

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to put resource files (like `prices_usd.txt`) in a package. Please put it under the `resources/` directory. If you put it directly in the `resources/` directory, you can access the file like this:

```
new FileReader(new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("prices_usd.txt").getFile()));
```

But if you really have a good reason to put it in the package, you can access it like this:

```
new FileReader("src/main/java/week5/practicum13/prices_usd.txt");
```

But this will not work when you export your project (for example: as a jar).

**EDIT 0:** Also of course, your file's name needs to be "prices_usd.txt" and not just "prices_usd".

**EDIT 1:** The first (recommended) solution does return a string on `.getFile()` which can not directly be passed to the `new File(...)` constructor when the application is built / not run in the IDE. [Spring](https://spring.io/) has a solution to it though: [org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html).

Simply use this code with Spring:

```
new FileReader(new ClassPathResource("prices_usd.txt").getFile());
```